# ListView of WebViews - reusing items of different height fails; asks for all views before displaying any

Tags: android, android-webview, android-listview, android-linearlayout

I have an activity that displays a `ListView`. Each item in the `ListView` is a `LinearLayout` consisting of one `WebView`. There are potentially hundreds of items in the list and each is a different height.

First problem is that when reusing a recycled view in `getView()`, the new view is always the height of the original view, even though I've set the `layout_height` for both the `LinearLayout` and the `WebView` to `wrap_content`.

Second problem is that `getView()` seems to be getting called for every item in the list even though only the first five or six fit on the screen. I haven't seen this when using other list item types. For example, in another place I a list of custom views that are all the same height and I only see `getView()` being called for the number of views that initially fit on the screen.

So... I need to figure out how to force recycled `WebViews` to render their new contents so their height can be calculated instead of just using the previous height. And I'd like to know why the system is asking me for ALL my items in this case.

Here's the requisite code snippets:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    >
    <ListView 
        android:id="@+id/topPane"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:dividerHeight="1.0px"
        android:divider="#FFFFFF"
        android:smoothScrollbar="false"
        />
</LinearLayout>
```

Rows are built from:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    >
    <WebView 
        android:id="@+id/rowWebView"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="0.0px"
        android:scrollbars="none"
        />
</LinearLayout>
```

This is getView() in my adapter. HTML snippets come from an array of Strings for now.

```
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
        {
        String item = (String) getItem(position);
        if (convertView == null)
            {
            convertView = (LinearLayout) LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.rowview, parent, false);
            }
        WebView wv = (WebView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.rowWebView);
        wv.loadDataWithBaseURL(null, item, "text/html", "utf-8", "about:blank");
        return convertView;
        }
```

Comment: Would like to know the answer to this, especially the row-height sticking on recycled views.

I have similar problem of a imageview that has "fill_parent" applied to it vertically, but the layout is designed to shrink to a minimum 100height. With hardcoded data it works, and on creation it works, but after recycling the view refuses to refresh all it's layout info and shrink to the minimum size.

I enforce the minimum size by having a 1px transparent view set to the minimum height of the row, and I have the entire layout row set to "wrap_content"

Comment: Try overriding [layoutChildern](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AbsListView.html#layoutChildren%28%29) on your ListView. There are a couple of examples using this method [here](http://www.devdaily.com/java/jwarehouse/android/core/java/android/widget/ListView.java.shtml) and [here](http://www.androidsnippets.com/simple-list-view). Another option I can think of is to call `getMeasuredHeight()` on the WebView so it gets actually measured, perhaps calling `invalidate()` to the listview after it.

Answer (score 5):

I think the problem is that with the code you wrote the system is measuring first the container height (row linear_layout), and later the content (WebView). But second measure doesn't affect the first one until you call invalidate or some method that makes the container to recalculate his size.

About why your getView method is called many times check your getViewTypeCount() method of your adapter.

```
 @Override
 public int getViewTypeCount()
 {
     return NumberOfTypeOfViewsInYourList;
 }
```

[Documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Adapter.html#getViewTypeCount%28%29) states that:

> "this method returns the number of
>   types of Views that will be created by
>   getView(int, View, ViewGroup). Each
>   type represents a set of views that
>   can be converted in getView(int, View,
>   ViewGroup). If the adapter always
>   returns the same type of View for all
>   items, this method should return 1.
>   This method will only be called when
>   when the adapter is set on the the
>   AdapterView."

I had a problem with this method, giving a big number (like 5000) made my app crash, it looks like it's used internally for some ListView calculations.

Hope it helps somehow.

BTW, there is a very good talk about [the world of ListViews](http://developer.android.com/videos/index.html#v=wDBM6wVEO70)

Comment: What do you mean by ``NumberOfTypeOfViewsInYourList`` is this the number of items in the List<>?

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem with my ExpandableListView. From other posts it seems to be an ongoing issue with multiple webviews in one list. The work around i found was to create and array of wewViews the first time getView is called, then subsequently return the webView at the correct index. Its a bit more memory intensive but it does'nt cause the view to resize.

```
SparseArray<WebView> wvGroup = new SparseArray<WebView>();
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    WebView wv = null;

    if (wvGroup.size() < 1) {
        for (int i = 0; i < sectionItems.size(); i++) {
            WebView webViewItem = new WebView(context);
            String htmlData = "<link rel=\"stylesheet\" type=\"text/css\" href=\"style.css\" />" + sectionItems.get(i).child_content;
            webViewItem.loadDataWithBaseURL("file:///android_assets/", htmlData, "text/html", "UTF-8", null);
            wvGroup.append(i, webViewItem);
        }


    }
    wv = wvGroup.get(groupPosition);
    wv.setPadding(30, 10, 10, 10);

return wv
```

Comment: A very dirty solution. But the best I've seen so far! You could make some kind of a pool of wvGroup, so you have a max number of webviews in memory.

Comment: It is a pretty dirty solution but it does work. The only problem i found was that couldnt get animations to work properly with all the webviews. Slowly expanding the listview, jumping to position etc. I eventually ended up scrapping the expandableListView and using javascript to get the accordion effect with a single webView. Its a bit slower it also works :)

Comment: What I do now is only getting the heights of the webviews and add them in an array. This works really nice as well. I've just added an separated answer to this question.

Answer (score 3):

I've tried the solution of sirFunkenstine which works great. Only the client, for which I'm building this app, didn't liked the performance. And I had to admit that it was not that smooth.

It seemed that adding and removing the preloaded WebViews where the problem. The UI got frozen for a split second every time the app added/removed the new WebView for the next row.

**Solution**

So I thought it would be better to only adjust the content and height of the WebView instead of adding/removing. This way we only have the amount of WebViews which are currently visible in memory. And we can use the reuse functionality of the ListView/Adapter.

So I've added a single WebView behind the ListView which constantly calculates the WebView height of the next items. You can get the height with the WebView method getContentHeight. You'll have to do this in the onPageFinished method so you have the final height. This raised another issue, cause the method returns zero when the content is loaded with loadDataWithBaseURL or loadData methods. It seems that the value is set eventually, but not yet at the time that the onPageFinished is called. To overcome this you can add a thread which constantly checks if the getContentHeight is not zero anymore. If it is not zero then the value is set and you can load the next one.

This whole solution is a bit hacky, but it gave me a nice and smooth ListView including WebViews with different heights.

Some example code:

**1: Queue the positions of the rows which you want to preload:**

```
private SparseArray<Integer> mWebViewHeights = new SparseArray<Integer>();
private LinkedBlockingQueue mQueue;
{
    mQueue = new LinkedBlockingQueue();
    try {
        mQueue.put(position);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

**2: Start the Runnable to constantly load new items from the queue and check/add the height to an array:**

```
Handler h;
Runnable rowHeightCalculator = new Runnable() {
    h = new Handler();
    rowHeightCalculator.run();
}
```

**3: Load new HTML content and check the heights:**

```
Handler h;
Runnable rowHeightCalculator = new Runnable() {

    int mCurrentIndex = -1;
    boolean mLoading = false;

    // Read the webview height this way, cause oncomplete only returns 0 for local HTML data
    @Override
    public void run() {
        if(Thread.interrupted())
            return;

        if (mCurrentIndex == -1 && mQueue.size() > 0) {
            try {
                mCurrentIndex = (Integer)mQueue.take();
                String html = mItems.get(mCurrentIndex).getPart().getText();

                mDummyWebView.clearView();
                mDummyWebView.loadDataWithBaseURL("file:///android_asset/reader/", "THE HTML HERE", "text/html", "UTF-8", null);
                    mLoading = true;
                }
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        if(mDummyWebView.getContentHeight() != 0 && mCurrentIndex >= 0) {
            int contentHeight = mDummyWebView.getContentHeight();
            mWebViewHeights.append(mCurrentIndex, contentHeight);
            mCurrentIndex = -1;
            mLoading = false;
        }

        // Reload view if we loaded 20 items
        if ((mQueue.size() == 0 && (mItemsCount - mQueue.size()) < 20) || (mItemsCount - mQueue.size()) == 20) {
            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }

        if (mQueue.size() > 0 || mLoading) {
            h.postDelayed(this, 1);
        }
    }
};
```

Answer (score 1):

My solution (even though I put the bounty up) for my problem was to put the ImageView into a FrameLayout, it than intelligently grew.

Invalidating the view or forcing layout calculations did nothing for me, but the framelayout container for the imageview seemed to solve everything. I assume this behaviour is in err, but the workaround was simple enough.

Maybe the same will apply to the OP's webview.

Comment: I've tried it, but didn't work for me (used WebView instead of ImageView).